# Как использовать один объект webdriver.Chrome() во всех процессах?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing

Всем привет. Необходимо с помощью selenium получить screenshot страниц сайта, которые под аутентификацией. Для этого создал функцию get_driver(), которая создает объект webdriver.Chrome() логинится на сайте и отдает объект dirver в глобальную переменную чтобы все воркеры (функции, которые делают screenshot) процессы работали с одним "аутентифицированным" объектом webdriver. Однако при запуске multiprocessing.Poll(initialzier=get_driver) "хитрый" удаленный хост разрывает соединение. Видимо нельзя одновременно из нескольких процессов сидеть на сайте как один аутентифицированный юзер. Если же в каждом воркере создавать отдельного аутентифицированного юзера - все работает, но хуже чем в синхронном варианте.
Вопрос: как с помощью selenium использовать один экземпляр аутентифицированного целевым сайтом webdriver в multiprocessing python'a?

Comment: а код не проще привести было? чтобы лучше понимать что здесь происходит?

Comment: Михаил Ребров, не могу:) С радостью бы. Но нельзя:)